# Why is my original nested list changing when copying?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a function that is given a nested list, and deletes all occurrences of elements in to_eliminate. I understand why I would have this problem if I did `new_list = input_list`, but im doing `new_list = input_list[:]`. I even checked their id's and they are definitely different. I don't want to modify my original list.

Both segments of code do not work.
When I return both `input_list` and `new_list`, I get the same result. I don't understand why, since I copied the original list, and they are two different objects.

Comment: This is only a shallow copy, sublists aren't cloned.

Comment: Why do you return the given `input_list` instead of `new_list`? Seems like you directly remove from the given list.

Comment: I return both, and they are the same thing.

Comment: `new_list = copy.deepcopy(input_list)`.

Comment: is there an alternate way to do this without using the copy module?

Answer (score 2):

Your fundamental problem is that `input_list[:]` only shallow copies; if it contains mutable contents itself (in this case, nested `list`s) it's sharing *aliases* to mutable data, and modifying it in the "copy" is still modifying the contents of the original data structure.

If you can't use the `copy` module, and you've got a known 2D arrangement of `list`s, just perform the deep copy yourself, changing:

```
new_list = input_list[:]
```

to:

```
new_list = [sublst[:] for sublst in input_list]
```

and making sure to `return new_list` rather than `input_list`. That list comprehension just manually makes shallow copies of the *second* layer of `list`s into a brand new `list`. You can extend it further to greater levels of nesting, but it gets progressively more ridiculous the deeper you go.

The real answer is to let Python do the work for you, with `copy.deepcopy`, making it:

```
new_list = copy.deepcopy(input_list)
```

which will work no matter how deeply nested your data structure gets.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, if you need it inline, let me know and i'll update the answer, i was unsure based on your question:

```
input_list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[3,5,7,9,0],[1,2,3,4,5]]
remove_list = [1,4,7,0]

def eliminate(input_list, remove_list):
  new_list=[]
  for item in input_list:
    new_list.append(list(set(item) - set(remove_list)))
  return new_list

new_list = eliminate(input_list, remove_list)

new_list
[[2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9], [9, 3, 5], [2, 3, 5]]
```